# How to have intermediate table for a 1 to many relationship?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have a model class:

```
public class UserProfile
{
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public ICollection<AddressMaster> AddressMaster { get; set; }
}
```

The above class have a 1 to many relationship with AddressMaster model class given below:

```
public class AddressMaster
{
        public string AddrID{ get; set; }
        public string AddressLine1{ get; set; }
        public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
        public TheatreLocation TheatreLocation { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is, there is one other model also that has a 1 to many relationship with addressmaster, which is:

```
public class TheatreLocation
{
        public string LocationID { get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public ICollection<AddressMaster> AddressMaster { get; set; }
}
```

So instead of having foreign key at the addressmaster, how can we have a intermediate table between addressmaster and the userprofile & another such table b/w addressmaster and theatre?

Or am i getting the whole concept wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So instead of having foreign key at the addressmaster, how can we have
> a intermediate table between addressmaster and the userprofile &
> another such table b/w addressmaster and theatre?

If you do not want to set any foreign key and add a intermediate table.Design like below:

```
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }       
}
public class AddressMaster
{
    [Key]
    public string AddrID { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
}
public class UserAddress
{       
    [Key]
    public string AddrID { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
}
```

Add the primary key to the intermediate table `UserAddress`.The `AddrId` could only has one value,but the `UserID` could have many value which is like `one-to-many` relationship.

> Or am i getting the whole concept wrong?

Nothing wrong.Using navigation property like what you did is also good.

Comment: Hi, I'd like to believe I did.
I'll extend the question with the controller code as well, so that anyone looks this up can get the full idea of how this works. Thanks for the help btw :)

Answer (score 2):

Your table definitions would probably wind up something like this:

```
UserProfile
    UserId PK

Theather
    TheatreId PK

Address
    AddrID PK
    AddressLine1 

UserAddress
    UserId PK & FK
    AddressId FK

TheatreAddress
    TheatreID PK & FK
    AddressId FK
```

This is just good normalisation - i.e. you have a generic 'address' table in the database.  Several entities may have an address and have either one-many or many-many relationships with addresses, but a specific address only needs to be recorded once.

The PK on the intermediate table only on the UserId (for example) ensures that this is one-many and not many-many.